# How to update binding source for checkbox from template?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

I have a template (`TextBlock` + `CheckBox`) for items in `LonglistSelector` but I wasn't able to figure out how to refresh binding. The `CheckBox` is bound to a boolean property. Only way that worked so far was to navigate to same XAML page with different parameter however this "solution" is unusable.

I've found some examples how to use `UpdateSource()` with `TextBox` but none with `CheckBox` from template.

Here is my `CheckBox` from teplate. Many things are probably useless, I tried everything I found. Binding is working but it does not refresh so I have to navigate to another page for example and then it is refreshed.

```
<CheckBox BorderThickness="2" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          x:Name="TemplateCheckBox" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsDone, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Checked="TemplateCheckBox_Checked"
                          Unchecked="TemplateCheckBox_Checked"
                          />
```

EDIT: I found easy way how to update items in `LonglistSelector`. Just create another empty `List` set it as a `ItemsSource` and just afterwards set original list as `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<CheckBox BorderThickness="2" **Loaded="OnLoaded"**
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          x:Name="TemplateCheckBox" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsDone, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Checked="TemplateCheckBox_Checked"
                          Unchecked="TemplateCheckBox_Checked"
                          />

private List<CheckBox> chkList=new List<CheckBox>();

private void OnLoaded(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   if(!chkList.Contians(sender as CheckBox))
   {
     chkList.Add(sender as CheckBox);
   }
}

private void UpdateSource()
{
   foreach(CheckBox chk in chkList)
   {
     chk.GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsChekcedProperty).UpdateSource();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that my problem would be finally solved but it does not work. It add all CheckBoxes to the list and go through them but it does not see that they were changed. "Refreshing" via my navigation solution still works so there shouldn't be problem somewhere else in code.